# Fatal exception #asynk task

Tags: android, asynchronous, task

i'm a new Andorid  noob :) ... and my first question on SO :)

So what i want to do:

I use a button to login with Facebook, i receive the GraphUser and i call a service to register the user with his facebook data in database.
The register is done in Asynk task.
I receive the json from service and on onPostExecute I want to make another call to other service with the database userId that i received from json,
also in an asynk task to get other data an then populate the view.
Here is where i get the asynk task exception on doInBackground. I've done someting wrong?

Here is the call for register with his facebook data:

```
public class GetUserFacebookDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    Activity activity;
    String fbNameParam;
    String fbEmailParam;
    String passwordParam = "";
    String android_id = "";
    String fbGengerParam;

    public GetUserFacebookDataTask(String fbNameParam, String fbEmailParam,
            final Activity current_activity, String android_id,
            String fbGengerParam) {
        this.activity = current_activity;
        this.fbNameParam = fbNameParam;
        this.fbEmailParam = fbEmailParam;
        this.android_id = android_id;
        this.fbGengerParam = fbGengerParam;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.d("GetUserFacebookDataTask doInBackground",
                "GetUserFacebookDataTask");

        Map<String, Object> paramsSend = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        paramsSend.put("name", fbNameParam);
        paramsSend.put("email", fbEmailParam);
        paramsSend.put("password", "");
        paramsSend.put("deviceToken", android_id);
        paramsSend.put("deviceType", 2);
        paramsSend.put("withFacebook", 1);

        if (fbGengerParam.equals("male")) {
            fbGengerParam = "m";
        } else {
            fbGengerParam = "f";
        }

        paramsSend.put("gender", fbGengerParam);

        String stausHandler = null;

        JsonObject response = null;
        try {
            response = WebServiceApi.PostToServiceLoginFacebook("login",
                    paramsSend);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (response != null) {
            JsonObject jsonData = ((JsonObject) response.get("userData"));

            JsonElement userPhotoUrl = jsonData.get("userPhotoUrl");
            JsonElement userPhoto = jsonData.get("userPhoto");
            JsonElement userNewEmail = jsonData.get("userNewEmail");
            JsonElement userAge = jsonData.get("userAge");

            String userPhotoUrlf = "";
            String userPhotof = "";
            String userNewEmailf = "";
            String userAgef = "";

            if (userPhotoUrl.toString().equals("null")) {
                userPhotoUrlf = "-";
            }

            if (userPhoto.toString().equals("null")) {
                userPhotof = "-";
            }

            if (userNewEmail.toString().equals("null")) {
                userNewEmailf = "-";
            }

            if (userAge.toString().equals("null")) {
                userAgef = "-";
            }

            UserData userData = new UserData(userPhotoUrlf, jsonData.get(
                    "userHeightInterval").toString(), jsonData.get(
                    "userCity").toString(), userPhotof, jsonData.get(
                    "userPassword").toString(), jsonData.get("userStyle")
                    .toString(), jsonData.get("userEmail").toString(),
                    jsonData.get("userDateRegistered").toString(), jsonData
                            .get("userConfirmed").toString(), jsonData.get(
                            "userWithFacebook").toString(), jsonData.get(
                            "userID").toString(), jsonData
                            .get("userGender").toString(), jsonData.get(
                            "userWantsPushNotifications").toString(),
                    jsonData.get("userName").toString(), userNewEmailf,
                    userAgef, jsonData.get("userShape").toString());

            UserData data = AppManager.getInstance().setUserData(userData);

            if (userData != null) {

                JsonElement status = response.get("status");

                stausHandler = status.toString();

            }
        }

        return stausHandler;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String status) {

        Log.d("GetUserFacebookDataTask onPostExecute",
                "GetUserFacebookDataTask onPostExecute");

        StatusHandlerLoginFb(status.toString(), activity);
    }

}
```

//status handler from the json received

```
public void StatusHandlerLoginFb(String status, Activity currentActivity) {

    if (status.equals("0")) {
        Log.d("StatusHandlerLoginFb", "StatusHandlerLoginFb");
        Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity,
                NavigationActivity.class);
        currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
        //new GetPhotoDataTaskFb(currentActivity).execute();
        new GetPhotoDataTask(currentActivity).execute();
    }
}
```

// the other task

public class GetPhotoDataTask extends
            AsyncTask> {

```
    Activity activity;

    public GetPhotoDataTask(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d("GetPhotoDataTask onPreExecute", "GetPhotoDataTask onPreExecute");
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Preluare Date",
                "Va rugam asteptati!");
    }

    @Override
    protected List<PhotoData> doInBackground(Void... params) {


        Log.d("GetPhotoDataTask doInBackground", "GetPhotoDataTask doInBackground");
        MyStyleApi myStyleApi = new MyStyleApi();

        List<PhotoData> photoData = null;

        try {
            photoData = myStyleApi.getPhotoDataWithDispatch();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<String> photoStr = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < photoData.size(); i++) {
            photoStr.add(photoData.get(i).getPhotoURL());
        }

        String[] photoUrls = new String[photoStr.size()];
        photoUrls = photoStr.toArray(photoUrls);

        AppManager.getInstance().setphotoUrls(photoUrls);

        List<PhotoData> photoDataS = AppManager.getInstance().setPhotoData(
                photoData);

        return photoData;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... percent) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Preluare Date",
                "Va rugam asteptati!");
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<PhotoData> photoData) {

        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

//getPhotoDataWithDispatch and the other method to receive data

```
// get PhotoData with userId as param
public List<PhotoData> getPhotoDataWithDispatch() throws JSONException,
        ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    Log.d("getPhotoDataWithDispatch ", "getPhotoDataWithDispatch ");

    UserData data = AppManager.getInstance().getUserData();
    final String userID = data.getUserID();

    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("userID", userID);

    JsonArray response = WebServiceApi.PostToServiceWithStringResponse(
            "images/get_images_data", params);

    if (response != null) {

        List<PhotoData> photoDataList = new ArrayList<PhotoData>();
        photoDataList = parseJsonArrayForFotoData(response);
        return photoDataList;

    }

    return null;
}
```

// the log cat

```
06-01 14:44:27.400: D/getUserDataFacebookLogin2(24790): getUserDataFacebookLogin2
06-01 14:44:27.410: D/GetUserFacebookDataTask doInBackground(24790): GetUserFacebookDataTask
06-01 14:44:27.410: D/PostToServiceLoginFacebook(24790): PostToServiceLoginFacebook
06-01 14:44:27.940: D/GetUserFacebookDataTask onPostExecute(24790): GetUserFacebookDataTask onPostExecute
06-01 14:44:27.940: D/StatusHandlerLoginFb(24790): StatusHandlerLoginFb
06-01 14:44:27.980: D/GetPhotoDataTask onPreExecute(24790): GetPhotoDataTask onPreExecute
06-01 14:44:28.040: D/GetPhotoDataTask doInBackground(24790): GetPhotoDataTask doInBackground
06-01 14:44:28.040: D/getPhotoDataWithDispatch(24790): getPhotoDataWithDispatch 
06-01 14:44:28.070: D/memalloc(24790): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4ddae000 size:8110080 offset:7618560 fd:66
06-01 14:44:28.190: W/dalvikvm(24790): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c541f8)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at com.example.palashfashion.webservice.WebServiceApi.PostToServiceWithStringResponse(WebServiceApi.java:166)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at com.example.palashfashion.webservice.MyStyleApi.getPhotoDataWithDispatch(MyStyleApi.java:97)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at com.example.palashfashion.webservice.MyStyleApi$GetPhotoDataTask.doInBackground(MyStyleApi.java:877)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at com.example.palashfashion.webservice.MyStyleApi$GetPhotoDataTask.doInBackground(MyStyleApi.java:1)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-01 14:44:28.200: E/AndroidRuntime(24790):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Could you please edit your post to include the LogCat output, and the code from your AsyncTask? Otherwise, we're forced to guess what's wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: The reason it's crashing is because `WebServiceApi.PostToServiceWithStringResponse` is not returning a Json array

Comment: got it :) many thanks... i managed to solve it

Comment: @user184994 Make your comment an answer please.

Comment: @algui91 I've posted the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's crashing is because `WebServiceApi.PostToServiceWithStringResponse` is not returning a Json array